# Is there a better MySql query that's more efficient

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, database-design

I have a query I built up with a little help from web searching, however it is not efficient with the large dataset I have. I set the query running 10 days ago and it's not finished.  I have no idea how far it has actually gotten either.  I'm fairly sure that the ORDER BY part isn't required, I don't know how much extra it is adding to the process.

```
INSERT INTO search_table (TEXT_ID, UPRN, SOURCE_ID) 

SELECT t.TEXT_ID, UPRN, s.SOURCE_ID FROM origin_table stc 

INNER JOIN text_source t ON stc.INDEX_TEXT = t.SOURCE_TEXT 
INNER JOIN index_source s ON stc.SOURCE_COL = s.SOURCE_COL 

GROUP BY t.TEXT_ID, s.SOURCE_ID 
ORDER BY t.TEXT_ID, s.SOURCE_ID
```

I ran an explain query with the following results:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | s | ALL | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 6 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | t | ALL | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 2627372 | Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)" |
| 1 | SIMPLE | stc | ALL | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 39603700 | Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join) |

Any help or suggestions in optimizing this query are appreciated.  I'm more than willing to learn more about what's going on and how I can improve it.

Edit: I've been asked about the actual data and purpose of the query.

I need a way to quickly lookup keywords used in a master dataset.  Keywords and their locations have been identified.  The same keywords appear many, many times and it is possible they could appear in any 1 of 6 columns within the master dataset.  The master dataset contains only one index, the Primary Key.  The other complication I have is each database is limited to 1Gb in size.  I can have 100 databases each up to 1Gb, but not 1 database of 100Gb.

My goal here was to basically creating an index in a database of its own that could be queried when needed, providing a pointer to the actual master record (and possibly what database it may later come to lie in.)  Alternatively, assuming I split the master database into <1Gb chunks, I would have to perform a full text query on around 30 different databases.

Data wise:

The text_source SOURCE_TEXT is basically a set of keywords which are found in a master dataset.  There are some 2.5m keywords.

The index_source SOURCE_COL is a list of 6 of the columns contained within the master dataset.  There are therefore just 6 rows.

The origin_table is a table consisting of 4 columns, a PrimaryKey, SEARCH_TEXT which is the keyword, SOURCE_COL which identifies where the keyword came from, and UPRN which is the Unique Primary Key where the data was originally found.  Both SEARCH_TEXT and SOURCE_COL are text fields.  There are nearly 40m rows each specifying where the keywords were found.

The destination search_table is basically the above origin table removing the heavily duplicated data and replacing it with an appropriate key

```
CREATE TABLE `origin_table` (
  `PrimaryKey` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SEARCH_TEXT` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPRN` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `SOURCE_COL` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PrimaryKey`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39845281 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

CREATE TABLE `search_table` (
  `PrimaryKey` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `INDEX_TEXT` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPRN` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `SOURCE_COL` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PrimaryKey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3

CREATE TABLE `index_source` (
  `SOURCE_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SOURCE_COL` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SOURCE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3

CREATE TABLE `text_source` (
  `TEXT_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `INDEX_TEXT` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TEXT_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2686936 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: Sample data and an explanation of what the query should be doing would help.  That said, a simple `group by` with some joins is rather hard to optimize, unless you can eliminate the aggregation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added an explanation as to what I am aiming to do.  I don't know whether I need the group by, I was assuming that it was serving to avoid duplication.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 4 tables, the size (in GB) of the 3 source tables, RAM size, and the values of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `join_buffer_size`.  I can't tell whether there are a few missing indexes, or running out of RAM or maybe something else.

Comment: @basha04 I guess my aim was to create an index.  Added more info about the tables to the post. Again I am not sure whether I need an order by clause, as long as the records are separated the order doesn't matter as I can index the product.  Would it be beneficial to create an index before running my query?  The origin_table will be redundant once the query is finished.

Comment: Meanwhile, since the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are identical, the `ORDER BY` is probably "free"; don't worry about keeping/removing it.  (I may amend this statement after seeing the schema.)

Comment: I really mean `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; words all too often leave out important details.

Comment: `stc.INDEX_TEXT` -- This seems wrong??  Note:  `FROM origin_table stc`

Comment: Aside from this query, do you ever use `TEXT_ID` or `SOURCE_ID`?  I ask because they seem to exist only for that "lookup" ("normalization").

Comment: @RickJames Sorry I was editing it to do just that. also PC has 32Gb RAM (Ryzen 5900X), stc=2.5GiB, t=111Mib and s=32KiB.  pool size=259232,  join buffer size=262144.  I have installed MariaDB on my local machine to manipulate before it gets pushed onto the real server.

Comment: @RickJames INDEX_TEXT = SEARCH_TEXT sorry the field got renamed, and I copy that line from where I have been documenting everything I do.  Keeping total records in case it all goes wrong and I have to repeat/restart.  And Nope just using them for "Normalization" and hopefully space-saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Never' use `TINYTEXT`, it is functionally equivalent to `VARCHAR(255)`, but has some drawbacks.

`SOURCE_COL` and `INDEX_TEXT` are sometimes declared `INT UNSIGNED`, sometimes `TINYTEXT` -- This inconsistency can lead to surprises.  Quite likely it is causing the terrible performance here.

The `GROUP BY` is technically improper.  (cf `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`) because of `UPRN`.

And change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` from a tiny 259K to 16G.

Comment: SOURCE_COL and INDEX_TEXT are TINYTEXT in the origin table but they become key values in the final table.
Can I just drop the GROUP BY and ORDER BY?
Good Tip on TINYTEXT, it looked easy!

Comment: @AdamSlade - It will be much less confusing to have the INTs called `SOURCE_ID` and `TEXT_ID`.  I took the liberty of changing your Question.